# prove a sequence of functions converges but its derivative does not converge

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $(g_n) \subseteq C[0,1] $ given by $g_n(x) = x^n/n$.
Show that $g_n \rightarrow 0$ in the metric space $C[0,1]$, but $g'_n$ does not converge in $C[0,1]$.  The metric space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the metric: $d(f,g) = sup\{|f(x) - g(x)| : x \in [a,b]   \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show that $g_n \to 0$ in $C[0,1]$, we need to show that $d(g_n, 0) = \operatorname{sup} \{ |g_n(x) - 0 | ~:~x \in [0,1] \} \to 0$. Now we can note that $d(g_n,0) = \frac{1}{n}$ by observing that $|g_n(x)|$ has a maximum of $\frac{1}{n}$ at $x=1$ for all $n$.

As for $g_n'$, you correctly note that $g_n'(x) = x^{n-1} \not \to 0$...why?

Comment: thanks a lot. $g'_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \in [0,1)$. when $x = 1$, $g'_n(x) \rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 1):

Theorem : Let $I$ be an interval and a sequence of functions ${f_n}$ be unifromly convergent on $I$ to the function $f$ Let $c$ be a point in $I$ where each $f_n$ is continuous .Then $f$ is continuous at $c$ .
Each $g'_n $ is pointwise convergent on $[0,1]$ to the function $g$ where $g$ is defined as
$g(x)=1$ only at point $x=1$ and otherwise zero. Clearly $g$ can't be continous . So $g'_n$ doesn't converge uniformly .